# Sending FormData() with axios in VueJS returns empty array in Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, form-data

I am trying to post my data using FormData() with axios. Laravel is my Backend.
When I try to `dd` (die and dump) my `$request->all()` in my Controller I get an empty array `[]`.

Here's my code which handles the post:

```
data() {
    let formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('first_name', 'Max');
    formData.append('first_name', 'Sample');

    return formData;
}

submit(requestType, url) {
    console.log(this.data().get('first_name')); // Output is correctly 'Max'

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios[requestType](url, this.data())
            .then(response => {
                this.onSuccess(response.data);

                resolve(response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.onFail(error.response.data)

                reject(error.response.data);
            });
    });
} 

sendData() {
    const id = 123;
    this.submit(patch, '/persons/' + id);
}
```

However if I format my data like this:

```
data() {
    let data = {
        'first_name': 'Max',
        'last_name': 'Sample'
    };

    return data;
}
```

I have the right output with `dd($request->all()` in my Controller.

**EDIT**

I found the reason for my problem. It is related to the HTTP method `patch`. If I use `post` instead the data is send successfully. It must be related to the headers being send but I could not find a solution yet.

Comment: Can you show the full code ? where the FormData(); is coming from ? are you getting any error in  browser console ?

Comment: Not sure about form data, but using a form with v-on:submit="" together with input v-model="" and a button that simply submits the form gives you much more controll in my opinion. By your example, it seems you try to post simple string values, which is one more reason to try out a "manual" submit.

Comment: Axios `get()` method should be like this `.get(url, {params: this.data()})`. Note that second parameter is `config` object where you need to specify the `params`. More at [axios docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#example)

Comment: @ljubadr Sending with the params attribute did not help. Like described in my question I can build up the data with a simple object `let data`... and the axios request is working perfectly fine.
@MarcoVeríssimo https://www.javascripture.com/FormData

Comment: Edited my question.